# Does JUnit 3 have something analogous to @Ignore

Tags: java, junit

I'm forced to use JUnit 3.  If I were using JUnit 4, I would occasionally use `@Ignore` since several of my tests take a bit of time.

Is there anything analogous in JUnit 4?  Commenting out tests is sloppy, and changing the name (from `testXxx()`) could lead to forgotten tests.  `@Ignore` is great, because it always reminds you which tests were not run.

Does anyone have a best practice for running some of a test classes methods in JUnit 3?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't know any other solution apart from commenting out tests or renaming them. I would go for the renaming option and use my own convention. For example all of them will start with ignoreXXX(). Then you can do one find/replace with your editor and you are ready.

Comment: Yes. JUnit 3 reflectively looks for methods starting with "test" to execute.

Answer (score 11):

In order to *conditionally* ignore tests in Robotium / JUnit 3, I override `runTest()` like

```
@Override
protected void runTest() throws Throwable {
    // Do nothing if the precondition does not hold.
    if (precondition) {
        super.runTest();
    }
}
```

Tests which are ignored this way will show up as "Success" in Eclipse, but as there is no "Ignored" state with JUnit 3, this is the best I was able to get.

Comment: In my experience, I also had to add the precondition to the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods, as they get called outside of the `runTest()` method.  For example:
`protected void tearDown() throws Exception {     if (precondition) super.tearDown(); } }`

Answer (score -1):

you can prepend the method with failing, so all methods like failingtest***() will be ignored during the junit run.

Comment: Please keep an eye out for when posts have been written, and whether they are still in need of an answer!