# java writing ignore test cases

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am studing how to create java test cases. In internet I saw two structures:

```
public class XXX {
    @Test
    @Test
}
```

And

```
public class XXX extends TestCase {
    //test cases
}
```

I am trying to use the second one but I can not create ignore case. In first example I can use *@Ignore*. What about the second one?

Answer (score 3):

The second method is the *old* method with JUnit (up to JUnit 3). It doesn't use Annotations (those things that start with `@`).

The new method uses Annotations (`@Test` and `@Ignore` to name just two).

If you insist on using the old method (JUnit 4), check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061650/does-junit-3-have-something-analogous-to-ignore) for more information.

Comment: No. New method is ok. I just thought it is different solutions.